# Do CSS ems always represent the font size?

Tags: css, font-size

From what I know, the em keyword in CSS means the current size of a font.

So if you put 1.2 em, it means 120% of the font height.

It doesn't seem right though that em is used for setting the width of divs etc like YUI grids does:

```
margin-right:24.0769em;*margin-right:23.62em;
```

Everytime I read about em, I forget what it really represents.

I'm hoping someone can explain it to me so it sticks in my head heeh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically it is the width of an "M" in the font. Hence the name!
In CSS2.1 it is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#em-width) to be the same as the font-size.

In many cases it seems more natural to use em rather than points or pixels, because it is relative to the font size. For example you might define a text-column to have a width of 40em. If you later decide to change the font-size, the column will still keep the same number of letters per line.

Comment: thanks for the 'hence the name comment', I can remember it now hopefully!

Comment: As an aside, people (well, mozilla) recommend ex over em because it better maps to pixels. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Em_units_versus_ex_units

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, em is the width of the upper case M. In practise though, an em is the point size of the font.

[em dash versus en dash](http://comm415.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/em-dash-versus-en-dash/).

Answer (score 3):

It does mean the size of the font, but using it for width/height is useful for creating designs that scale with the font-size. This is becoming less useful now that most browsers can do full page zoom. Before when they could only change the size of the text, using em for width/height would allow those elements to scale also.

Answer (score 1):

An em size is proportional to its containing element.

For example:

```
<!-- Browser default size (usually 16px) -->
<div style="font-size: 1.00em;">
    <!-- 150 % of the container's size: 16 + (16/2) = 24 -->
    <div style="font-size: 1.50em;">
```

[This editor](http://riddle.pl/emcalc/) keeps it in mind for me (as to how it works).

Answer (score 0):

They are re-calculating exact pixel values to `em` to make them scalable.

See this [on-line calculator](http://riddle.pl/emcalc/) for example.